# Remove part of Routing in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, episerver

I wanna change one of my routes in a EPiServer CMS, MVC.

**From**

http://myDomain.com/modules/EpiCase/About/Index

**TO**

http://myDomain.com/EpiCase/About/Index

I tried make a new route. When I try it I get 404 erro

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "EPiCase_Default",
               url: "EPiCase/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: What kind of controller is ActionController, what does it inherit?

Comment: Sorry @EricHerlitz but I don't understand your question.

Comment: What are you hosting under EPiCase (i.e pagedata or custom mvc) and why do you want to have custom routing for the pages? Normally you use the page tree to build the structure of your pages and not the MVC pattern.

Comment: This applications is a Gadget inside the EPiServer ( a powerful CMS ). This CMS put my gadget in this structure. And I would like create a alternative route it means, the url /EPiCase/About/Index will to /modules/EpiCase/About/Index

Comment: Been working with EPi since 2002 :) Anyway, the gadgets are usually for internal use in the EPi dashboard or edit gui, is this where you want it or do you want external users to access the gadget?

Comment: Yes. My idea is create a gadget with internal access in the Dashboard normally but if you wanna access directly look like a page.

Comment: Probably yes, but I wonder how much of an bad idea it is. I'd say you are better of constructing a real block for this instead and separate the gadget and external component

Comment: But Can I install a block and a Page with this block from a Nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Try deriving from `System.Web.Routing.RouteBase`. Here is a a sample implementation. I think you will need to modify this to fit your application.

```
public class AlternateRoute : RouteBase
{

    private string[] alternateUrls;
    public AlternateRoute(params string[] urls){alternateUrls = urls;}
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData result = null;
        string requestedURL =
            httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
        if (alternateUrls.Contains(requestedURL, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            result.Values.Add("controller", "About");
            result.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            result.Values.Add("alternateUrl", requestedURL);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData result = null;
        if (values.ContainsKey("alternateUrl") &&
            alternateUrls.Contains((string)values["alternateUrl"], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result =
                new VirtualPathData(
                    this,
                    new UrlHelper(requestContext).Content((string)values["alternateUrl"]).Substring(1)
                );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then add the desired route through constructor when adding `AlternateRoute` instance to `routes`.

```
routes.Add(new AlternateRoute("~/EpiCase/About/Index"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with **partial routing** in EPiServer 7: http://joelabrahamsson.com/custom-routing-for-episerver-content/